# Trying to Scan in an Array from DataSet but continue to get Bus Error in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, average, scanf

I am trying to scan in data from a DataSet in the terminal and end the data being pulled in when it reaches -1. But for some reason I continue to get an Bus Error or Segmentation Fault(core dumped) error. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?? I know its within the loop some where....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int i, dataset[200]={0}, count, sum;
float average = 0;

while(dataset[i] != -1)
{
   scanf("%i", &dataset[i]);
   sum += dataset[i];
   count++;
}

average = sum/count;

printf("The average is %f\n", average);

return 0;
```

}

I also want to eventually turn it into a function, but I'm trying to figure out how to scan in the dataset first and assign it to the dataset and stop pulling in numbers when it reaches the value -1.

Comment: You never increment `i` within the loop, so thats infinite loop.

Comment: I don't suppose you initalize `i` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `i` and update it within the loop.

```
i=0;
while(dataset[i] != -1 && i<200) //200 is size of array,
{
   scanf("%i", &dataset[i]);
   sum += dataset[i];
   count++;
   i++; //you can do away with count as you have i
}
```

As `i` is not initialized, when you refer `dataset[i]` it can go out of bound.

Comment: I implemented the code you re-corrected and I still get the Segmentation fault( core dumped) error.

Comment: I am compling the code, then i have a seperate file called      Dataset and when I do a.out<DataSet it gives me the error.

Comment: @Deej, you may also want to limit the loop till `i<200`

Comment: Okay, that actually relieved the segmentation error, but now I'm getting an output of -11. My Dataset includes (32 812 780 362 72 1 259 -1) @Rohan

Comment: It was incrementing i++ that actually gave the error of 11 ... I have no idea why that is now though....

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int i=0, dataset[200]={0}, count=0, sum=0;
float average = 0;

while(1)
{
scanf("%i", &dataset[i]);
if(dataset[i] == -1){
break;
}
sum += dataset[i];
    count++;
    i++;
}

average = sum/count;

printf("The average is %f\n", average);

return 0;
}
```

here is a simple way of doing this. i would ideally replace the while(1) with a typedef bool true false. also notice the if statement must be before we check for the -1. or else you are summing -1 into your sum, i assume your using -1 as an identifier of the end of the data.

whats wrong with your code.
1) this part of your code is flawed,

```
while(dataset[i] != -1)
{
scanf("%i", &dataset[i]);
sum += dataset[i];
count++;
i++ //i assumed you included i++ after reading some comments//
}
```

suppose you had -1 entered at the 200th element, then you would increment i to 201, and then your obviously out of bounds and have a set fault.

2) always initialise variables or else your getting garbage values stored in ram.

Comment: also looking at your original code notice after you increment i++, in the while loop you are check dataset[i],BUT the -1 was in dataset[i-1]; so you are pretty much in an infinite loop. and eventually seg fault